# Compute Jordan Form of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

How to find the Jordan form of the following matrix ( It's not necessary to find the jordanizing basis )?

$A =  \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} n & n-1 & \cdots & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & n & & 3 & 2 \\ \vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & & n & n-1 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n\end{array}\right) $

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $ \triangle_A(x) = ( x-n)^n $.

However, I don't see how to make any progress. I see that $ A = n\cdot I_n + B  $ where $ B = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 0 & n-1 & \cdots & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & & 3 & 2 \\ \vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & & 0 & n-1 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) $ is a nilpotent matrix of index $ n $, but how can I proceed?

Comment: What's the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to $n$?

Comment: Once you have both the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalues, you're done. You have one, what's the other?

Comment: I think the minimal polynomial has to be the same as the characteristic polynomial since $ A - n\cdot I $ is nilpotent of index $ n $, that's the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to $ n $.

Answer (score 1):

Show by induction that if $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)^t$ is an eigenvector of $B$, then $a_n=a_{n-1}=\cdots=a_2=0$. Hence the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $1$, which implies that $B$ has a single Jordan block.

However, in general the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are not sufficient to determine the Jordan canonical form: A $4\times 4$ matrix with a single eigevalue $\lambda$ of geometric multiplicity $2$ will have two Jordan blocks, but their sizes could be $1+3$ or $2+2$.